# Magma Isogeny Polynomials Coercion

Tags: polynomials, elliptic-curves, magma-cas

This is bordering the wrong stack exchange but I have the following problem:

I have the code;

```
R<X>:=PolynomialRing(GF(43)); 
F<i> := ext<GF(43)|X^2+1>;
E:=EllipticCurve([F|1,0]);
f:=TwoIsogeny(E![0,0]);
phi:=IsogenyMapPhi(f);
omega:=IsogenyMapOmega(f);
```

Now `phi` outputs as

```
$.1^2+ i*$.1
```

which has Type `RngUPolElt[FldFin]` and `omega` outputs as

```
$.1^2*$.2 + 41*i*$.1*$.2 + $.2
```

which has Type `RngMPolElt`

Now, what exactly is going on with magma and `$.1` and `$.2`? I'd like to coerce these two expression in the same multivariate polynomial ring, so that I can perform operations on them and plug them into other functions. In particular, I need `phi` to be of the type `RngMPolElt`.

Comment: What information are you trying to obtain from $\phi$ and $\omega$, it is unclear from the documentation what these functions do (at least to me). $\phi$ seems to be cutting out the kernel of the isogeny?

Comment: To actually answer the question, the ```$.1``` and ```$.2``` are placeholders which Magma uses to print polynomials in polynomial rings without named variables. In particular the pair of ```$.1```'s you have are not the same. To coerce into a multivariable polynomial ring is easy though. Just do ```P<x,y> := PolynomialRing(F,2); phi := Evaluate(phi, x); omega := Evaluate(omega, [x,y])```

Comment: Your code block returns an error as `P` is undefined. Please fix it. If you ever have an object displaying with unnamed generators, you can name them by assign its parent a name, e.g., `S<x,y> := Parent(omega);`.